# Ansible: Condition with "and" and boolean variable not working

Tags: ansible

I discovered the following problem when executing an ansible-playbook:

I have an `include_tasks:` command, that is dependent on 2 variables, a string variable and a boolean variable.

I first tried to write my code like this, which I thought should work fine:

```
- include_tasks: file.yml
  when: string_variable == "string" and bool_variable
```

Unfortunatelly, that didn't work, the tasks were included even if `bool_variable` is set to `false`. The variables are defined in the inventories-file in the `hosts`-folder:

```
[group]
server1      bool_variable=false       string_variable=string
server2      bool_variable=false       string_variable=string
```

In `file.yml`, I have the lines:

```
- debug:
    var: bool_variable
```

which prints `false` for each server. However, this line should not be reached, when the variable is `false`.

However, I found 2 ways to make the condition work:

Adding `== true`, which clearly seems redundant, since the condition than contains `false == true`:

```
- include_tasks: file.yml
  when: string_variable == "string" and bool_variable == true
```

and this (which shows that the `bool_variable` should be interpreted correctly):

```
- include_tasks: file.yml
  when: 
    - string_variable == "string" 
    - bool_variable
```

Why did the first condition not work? As far as I see, the condition should be evaluated correctly. Do I have to add parentesis or something similar?

I am using ansible 2.6.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any variable you set either in the INI format inventory or pass from CLI as extravars is a string.

You can verify it with the `type_debug` filter:

```
bool_variable | type_debug
```

The type is `unicode` when running Ansible with Python 2 and `str` when running in Python 3.

---

Use the following to cast it to Boolean in your conditionals:

```
bool_variable | bool
```

---

Some expressions work, because Ansible tries to match the string value to common (those defined in YAML) Boolean values.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the fast and detailed answer! It works as expected, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

can try this, if only Boolean param

```
when: STRING_PARAM|bool == true
```

when false with string parameter

```
when: STRING_PARAMETER == "PRODUCER" and BOOLEAN_PARAM|bool == false
```